# C# | Console Application | System.Int32[]

Tags: c#, консоль, int

Нужно вывести на экран:

int[] name = {1, 5, 77, 55, 464, 10};

Comment: Не сказано, каким способом вывести, не сказано, что вывести (строчка `int[] name = {1, 5, 77, 55, 464, 10};` может значить что угодно). Опишите проблему шире. Или это какой-то hello-world. [Wiki](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80_%C2%ABHello,_World!%C2%BB).

Comment: Телепатия подсказавает, что `Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", name))` должно помочь.

Answer (score 8):

```cs
Console.WriteLine("int[] name = {1, 5, 77, 55, 464, 10};");
```

Comment: Очень хорошо, спасибо. Добавил в закладки, буду ссылаться сюда в комментариях к неверно поставленным вопросам.

Answer (score 0):

Если в столбик нужно вывести:

```
int[] name = { 1, 5, 77, 55, 464, 10 };

foreach (var item in name)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Если в одну строку:

```
int[] name = { 1, 5, 77, 55, 464, 10 };

foreach (var item in name)
{
    Console.Write(item + " ");
}
```

Comment: либо воспользоваться `string.Join`

Comment: @timur Ответы на этот вопрос не имеют смысла. Кроме ответа timur, он смешной (: